# Removing the EFI partition from external HDD on OS X

Tags: macos, partitioning, efi

After formatting an external hard drive with OS X's diskutil, the disk is automatically split  into 2 partitions like so:

```
Finished partitioning on disk1
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Milosz Pass             499.7 GB   disk1s2
```

Now, since this is my external HDD that's not using for firmware upgrades/booting or whatever the EFI partition might be used for, I assume I might as well delete it and use the extra 200MB for something else. But how do I do that?

Using diskutil partitionDisk and explicitly stating that I only want 1 partition to be created, it *still* creates the EFI partition alongside the other one. Any hints I was able to find so far described how to do this under Windows, but surely there must be a way to do this on OS X as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I must yet find out what difference it makes, but</s>* choosing `MBR` as the partition map scheme gives the desired result.

Hence, running `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk1 1  MBRFormat HFS+ "Milosz Pass" 500G` on the same disk as [above](https://superuser.com/q/419353/50687), results in the following partition layout:

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS Milosz Pass             500.1 GB   disk1s1
```

Notice the ~400 MB space increase.

*<sub>Read up on the differences between the default GPT scheme and the MBR [here](http://www.petri.co.il/gpt-vs-mbr-based-disks.htm). Also have a look at common myths pertaining to partition map schemes, EFI and more [here](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/).</sub>